# Uniqueness of final velocities in law of conservation of momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Let's suppose that an object $A$ of mass $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ is moving with a velocity of $2\ \mathrm{m/s}$ and another object $B$ of mass $2\ \mathrm{kg}$ is moving with a velocity of $-1\ \mathrm{m/s}$ (in the opposite direction with respect to the motion of $A$)

So initial momentum is
$$p_{\text{initial}} = m_1 u_1 + m_2u_2 = (1)(2) + (2)(-1) = 0\ \mathrm{kg\ m/s}$$

This means that the final momentum $p_{\text{final}}$ will also be $0\ \mathrm{kg\ m/s}$.

Here, $m_1 = 1\ \mathrm{kg}$ and $m_2 = 2\ \mathrm{kg}$, let the final velocities of $A$ and $B$ be $x$ and $y$ respectively, so: $p_{\text{final}} = x + 2y = 0$ and this linear equation in two variables doesn't have one solution. The values of both $x$ and $y$ can be $0\ \mathrm{m/s}$ and they can also be $x=-2\ \mathrm{m/s}$ and $y=1\ \mathrm{m/s}$.

This means that the two objects can both stop after collision and can also move in the opposite directions as they were first moving in with the same speed. This states that their final velocities are not unique.

If the final velocities are not unique, it means that they depend on some factor, what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final velocities are indeed not unique. The final limiting factor is kinetic energy. Let's call the initial velocities $u_1,u_2$ and the final momenta $u_1',u_2'$ (otherwise the subscripts are going to get crowded). The condition of momentum conservation can be written as 
$$m_1u_1+m_2u_2=m_1u_1'+m_2u_2'.$$
If no energy is lost during the collision then the collision is [elastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision). The conservation of energy looks as follows.
$$\tfrac 1 2m_1u_1^2+\tfrac 1 2m_2u_2^2=\tfrac 1 2m_1u_1'^2+\tfrac 1 2m_2u_2'^2$$
If energy is lost then you can define $E'=\epsilon E$ where $\epsilon$ is a number between 0 and 1. This gives
$$\epsilon(\tfrac 1 2m_1u_1^2+\tfrac 1 2m_2u_2^2)=\tfrac 1 2m_1u_1'^2+\tfrac 1 2m_2u_2'^2$$
Using this additional constraint still leaves you with two possible solutions: one where the particles bounce off each other and one where the particle don't interact at all. This is because if the particles don't interact momentum and energy are also conserved.

Comment: Initial momenta? You mean, velocities, right?

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu oops yes

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand it completely

Comment: Please tell me if I understood your answer correctly. What I think you said is that there are two cases : 1) No energy conversions take place. In this case, what would be the status of the final velocities? Would they just be negatives of what they were earlier? 2) Some energy conversion is there and the final energy is some fraction of the initial energy. What would the status of final velocities in this case be? Random?

Comment: By the way, pardon me if I'm being annoying but is this 11th grade Physics or some higher level?

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu 1) This is almost true. In the so called 'center of momentum frame',which you used in your question, the total momentum is zero. In that case the velocities get reflected: $u_1'=-u_1$ and $u_2'=-u_2$.  Otherwise this is generally not true 2) The final velocities will still be well defined. In the center of momentum frame for example the velocities are reflected but also scaled by $\sqrt\epsilon$.

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu Ofcourse you're not annoying :). I first encountered this in the first year of my physics bachelor. It should be doable if you're below university level because it's just algebra but can take some time to understand.

Comment: Thanks, again...